# Unity stops responding based mesh vertex-count

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, while-loop, infinite-loop, flood-fill

I am running '**GenerateFloodFillData**' a number of times in another script. It loops the function in a for-loop based on an int variable **X**. If i only run the function once (**floodFillSampleRate** = 1) then it seems to respond every time. If i up **floodFillSampleRate** = 10 then Unity editor stops responding 25% out of a few tries. When **floodFillSampleRate** = 100 then it computes for a while and then stops responding and the process never 'goes back' to responding state. I know why the function takes very long time to compute and that it is also using a while-loop (which is not always recomended). But this should not be an infinity-loop/recursion issue because the function has been executed before.

I know realised that changed the meshChunkSize on my terrain (giving Vector3[] allVertices way lower elements) fixes the infinite 'not responding' on the process. So with around 2100 vertices it always runs through with any number on floodfillSampleRate. When i go up to around 15-20k vertices then it still works but unity stops responding for a few seconds, it then goes back to responding and outputs the result. If i go up to my default chunksize which is 59k vertices at even low values on floodFillSampleRate then it just is in 'not responding' mode for what looks to me infinite (I've waited around 25-30 minutes for the process to return but i didnt).

Is this some time-complexity issue that just makes it so that the more vertices that loops a few times the time it takes is just too long or something? I dont know the time-complexity exactly, but i would assume it atleast is linear, since adding more vertices means just more vertices to queue and loop in the while loop. I doesnt seem that i have an infinite-loop in the code either. I tried framing the whole function with a try-catch (im not sure if im doing this right) and i dont get any error, it just freezes so how can i get an error if unity process is not responding.

```
private static Queue<Vector3> q = new Queue<Vector3>();
private static List<Vector3> l = new List<Vector3>();

private static void CheckIfQueueNeighbor(int index, float limit, Vector3[] allVertices, Vector3 currentNode)
{
    if (allVertices[index].y - currentNode.y <= limit)
    {
        if (l.Contains(allVertices[index]) == false)
        {
            l.Add(allVertices[index]);
            q.Enqueue(allVertices[index]);
        }
        else
        {
            // Do nothing if already in list
        }
    }
}

public static float GenerateFloodFillData(float heightThresholdValue, MeshFilter meshFilter)
{
    Vector3[] verts = meshFilter.sharedMesh.vertices;
    Vector3 cNode;

    //Initialize
    int width = (int)meshFilter.sharedMesh.bounds.size.x;
    q = new Queue<Vector3>();
    l = new List<Vector3>();

    //Start at index 0, maybe be any corner or vertex in mesh. Investigate more.
    q.Enqueue(verts[0]);

    while (q.Count > 0)
    {
        cNode = q.Dequeue();

        //Add traversable nodes: Left, right, top & bottom
        if ((Array.IndexOf(verts, cNode) - 1) >= 0)
        {
            CheckIfQueueNeighbor(Array.IndexOf(verts, cNode) - 1, heightThresholdValue, verts, cNode);
        }
        if ((Array.IndexOf(verts, cNode) + 1) < verts.Length)
        {
            CheckIfQueueNeighbor(Array.IndexOf(verts, cNode) + 1, heightThresholdValue, verts, cNode);
        }
        if ((Array.IndexOf(verts, cNode) - width) >= 0)
        {
            CheckIfQueueNeighbor(Array.IndexOf(verts, cNode) - width, heightThresholdValue, verts, cNode);
        }
        if (Array.IndexOf(verts, cNode) + width < verts.Length)
        {
            CheckIfQueueNeighbor(Array.IndexOf(verts, cNode) + width, heightThresholdValue, verts, cNode);
        }
    }

    float averageTraversal = (float)l.Count / (float)verts.Length;
    return averageTraversal;
}
```

This function is run when GUILayout.Button is pressed:

```
        float floodFillAverageTraversal = 0f;
        for (int i = 0; i < mapPreview.floodFillSampleRate; i++)
        {
            floodFillAverageTraversal += FloodFill.GenerateFloodFillData(mapPreview.floodFillHeightThresholdValue, mapPreview.previewMeshFilter);

            mapPreview.maps[mapPreview.mapIndexSelector].heightMapSettings.noiseSettings.seed = Random.Range(0, int.MaxValue);
            mapPreview.DrawMapInEditor();
        }

        floodFillAverageTraversal /= mapPreview.floodFillSampleRate;
```

Comment: not related but general question: why `cNode = q.Peek(); q.Dequeue();` instead of directly `cNode = q.Dequeue();`? ... also I don't see where you are using `X` in your code ... could you explain what you mean by that?

Comment: Fixed X to proper variable  if you didnt see it

Comment: Do you anywhere have a `try-catch` in your code where the catch doesn't print out the error?

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that you are adding to "q" in "CheckIfQueueNeighbor" function so continuously Dequeuing and Queuing forever??

```
while (q.Count > 0)
    {
        cNode = q.Dequeue();
```

And

```
private static void CheckIfQueueNeighbor(int index, float limit, Vector3[] allVertices, Vector3 currentNode)
{
    if (allVertices[index].y - currentNode.y <= limit)
    {
        if (l.Contains(allVertices[index]) == false)
        {
            l.Add(allVertices[index]);
            q.Enqueue(allVertices[index]);
```

Comment: I'll look more into this. Might be something. Otherwise ill try some try-catch things as @Philipp said.

Comment: That should not be it no. Because in 'CheckIfQueueNeighbor' we first if its under a value. If it is we ONLY add it to list and queue if its not already in the list l. And if it is over the value then we dont even Enqueue the Vector3. We just add in the ones that are allowed, and when they are, they cannot be if they already are in list l.